# AngularJS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, filter

Не совсем понимаю как убрать ошибку такого типа:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider <-
>   startFromFilter

Прикладываю код объявления модуля, контроллера и фильтров:

```
    angular.module('dealersApp.history', ['ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('history', {
        url:"/history",
        templateUrl: 'history/history.html',
        controller: 'HistoryController'
    });
}]).controller('HistoryController', ['$rootScope','$scope','$location','Client', function ($rootScope,$scope,$location,Client) {
   //...
}]).filter('unique', function() {
    return function(collection, keyname) {
        var output = [],
            keys = [];


            angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                var key = '';
                if(keyname === 'Date') {
                    if(typeof item[keyname] !== "undefined") {
                        key = item[keyname].replace(/T[\d:]+/, '');
                    }
                } else {
                    key = item[keyname];
                }

                if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1 && typeof key !== "undefined") {
                    keys.push(key);
                    output.push(item);
                }
            });
        return output;
    };
}).filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

Также есть общий модуль со всеми зависимостями:

```
angular.module('dealersApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource',
    'dealersApp.login',
    'dealersApp.home',
    'dealersApp.catalog',
    'dealersApp.recovery',
    'dealersApp.actions',
    'dealersApp.sale',
    'dealersApp.new',
    'dealersApp.basket',
    'dealersApp.settings',
    'dealersApp.history',
    'dealersApp.edit',
    'dealersApp.refunds',
    'dealersApp.claims',
    'dealersApp.reclamations',
    'dealersApp.invoices',
    'dealersApp.integrationApi',
    'authService',
    'lbServices',
    'angucomplete-alt'
]).config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider','LoopBackResourceProvider','$httpProvider','$rootScopeProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider,LoopBackResourceProvider,$httpProvider,$rootScope) {
    $stateProvider.state('logout', {
        url:"/logout",
        template: '',
        controller: ['User', '$location','$rootScope',function(user,$location,$rootScope){
            user.logout();
            $rootScope.user = null;
            user.isAuthenticated();
            $location.path('/login'); //send to login page
        }]
    }).state('404', {
        url:"/404",
        template: '<div class="error-404">404 <br/>Страница не найдена</div>',
        controller: ''
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/').otherwise('/404');

    LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase(baseUrl+'/api/');

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, LoopBackAuth ,$rootScope) {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status == 401) {
                    LoopBackAuth.clearUser();
                    LoopBackAuth.clearStorage();
                    $rootScope.user = null;
                    $location.nextAfterLogin = $location.path();
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
}])
```

template:

```
     <select ng-model="orderStatus" class="filter" ng-change="filterOrders('Status', orderStatus); currentPage = 0;">
            <option value="">Select status</option>
            <option ng-repeat="order in infoOrders | unique : 'Status'" value="{{order.Status}}">{{ order.Status }}</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="orderDate" class="filter" ng-change="filterOrders('Date', orderDate); currentPage = 0;">
            <option value="">Select date</option>
            <option ng-repeat="order in infoOrders | unique : 'Date'" value="{{order.Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}">{{ order.Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</option>
        </select>
...
 <div ng-repeat="order in orders | startFrom: startingItem() | limitTo: itemsPerPage" class="item_block">
        <div class="head-order flex" ng-click="slider_open = !slider_open">
            <div class="fl-1">{{order.Number || "Номер еще не присвоен."}}</div>
            <div class="fl-1">{{order.Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' || order.created | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: для того чтобы использовать фильтр в контроллере нужно заинжектить сервис `$filter` и вызывать фильтр так: `$filter('startFrom')(...something...)`

Comment: я смотрела примеры и суть в том, что я не использую фильтр в самом контроллере, а только в template. Я приложила основные куски из template, где используется фильтр в основной пост.

Comment: если не используешь в контроллере тогда не нужно и пытаться его там заинжектить.

Comment: Ошибку выдает и с инжектами типа startFromFilter и uniqueFilter

Comment: убери инжект startFromFilter и uniqueFilter из контроллера

Comment: и не хватает запятой перед объявлением функции контроллера

Comment: Обновила актуальный код в основном посте. Ошибка осталась такая же.

Comment: а если закомментировать startFrom в шаблоне - unique срабатывает?

Comment: Нет. Он ругается на оба фильтра

Answer (score 0):

В итоге причина оказалась в кешировании страницы. Код рабочий.